# CPQ: How to verify if manually triggered recalculation is success?

Tags: apex, quote, cpq

We have a scenario that sometimes in CPQ, the ghost quotes which gets created does not automatically gets deleted because the internal CPQ calculation fails.
https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000316738&type=1&language=en_US&mode=1

To triggered a recalculation of Quotes we are just doing a dummy updates on such quotes.

```
List<SBQQ__QuoteLine__c> quoteLines = [SELECT Id,SBQQ__AdditionalDiscountAmount__c FROM SBQQ__QuoteLine__c WHERE SBQQ__Quote__c = 'QuoteId'];

if(!quoteLines.isEmpty()){
    quoteLines.get(0).SBQQ__AdditionalDiscountAmount__c = quoteLines.get(0).SBQQ__AdditionalDiscountAmount__c;
}

update quoteLines;
```

and the CPQ recalculation gets triggered internally. But how to verify that the recalculation is success, is there a way? Or we just add all Quote Line Items amount and verify if Opportunity Amount matches this.

**UDPATE (Just trying with Calculate API but : not working)**

When using Calculate API, I am getting this error:

```
08:07:35.852 (9852147514)|EXCEPTION_THROWN|[438]|System.SObjectException: SObject row was retrieved via SOQL without querying the requested field: Product2.SBQQ__PricingGuidance__c
```

Though the handler gets called successfully, I have no idea how to pass this as I am not using any query to feed Quote. I am using read api to read the Quote using Id.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may be able to query `SBQQ__RecordJob__c`. This is the same object that the [QuoteSave Visualforce page](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000314530&type=1&mode=1) uses to display the status to the user. It looks like the `SBQQ__RecordId__c` field will have the quote id plus the type of job that was run. For example: `a1z3m00000NyqQLAAZ::QuoteCalculator`.

Comment: This actually did work, but the only catch is the record gets created when you do a dummy update on QuoteLines and not when you use the QuoteCalculator API.

Answer (score 0):

Taking into account the async nature of the calculation you can leverage the existing Quote Calculator API which grants you the ability to attach a callback Apex class that is called after the calculation is finished (instead of forcing a DML), that way you can implement your handling logic after the calculation is finished.

> https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.cpq_dev_api.meta/cpq_dev_api/cpq_quote_api_calculate_final.htm

Comment: The API never work, its gives 200 as a response, but the recalculation never works. This I have already tried.